# Spring: How to set parameters in FilterConfig from XML context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My `NtlmAuthenticationfilter` overrides a 3rd party filter that requires some parameters to be set in the `FilterConfig` e.g.

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout</param-name>
            <param-value>60000</param-value>
        </init-param>
```

I am using Spring Security's `FilterChainProxy` so I do not wish to initialize my filters in the web.xml

Instead, I wish to initialize these as Spring beans and be managed by the Spring container.

How do I go about setting these `FilterConfig` parameters via Spring properties.

I've looked at the `GenericFilterBean` but its not clear how to do this

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java Config, you can do it like this:

```
@Bean(name="ntlmAuthenticationFilter")
public FilterRegistrationBean ntlmFilter() {
    NtlmAuthenticationFilter filter = new NtlmAuthenticationFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout", "60000");
    registration.setInitParameters(params);
    return registration;
}
```

(I haven't used the filter you are describing, so its possible I have the classname wrong)